# Need to look up a description for an id from database; can i use struts type converter?

Tags: struts2, enums, struts, typeconverter, struts-action

I have an id in the bean and mapped in orm.xml to database.  For each id I have to lookup description from database and display.  If I have enum values R:"RED" G:"GREEN".  Struts does type conversion using EnumConverter.  I just want to do similar stuff; if id = 123 what is the product description (lookup).   Can I use Struts converter by setting action.properties or by extending StrutsTypeConverter to lookup description for an id = 123?  Please let me know if there are any other suggestions.
In short:- Each id I want to lookup description; where description is not part of the bean.

Product Bean

```
public class Product{
private Long id;
private String description;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String planDescription) {
    this.description = planDescription;
}
}
```

Manage Bean

```
public class Manage{
private Long id;
private String Currency;
..and so on

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

<setters>..<getters>
}
```

Admin Action uses Manage Bean for all fields on UI

```
public class ManageAction extends ActionSupport
{
private Collection<Item> allItems;
private Manage manage;

public Collection<Item> getAllItems() {
    return allItems;
}

public void setAllItems(Collection<Item> allItems) {
    this.allItems = allItems;
}
}
```

`.jsp` file action = ManageAction

```
<s:label key="color" value="#color" />
<s:label key="id" value="%{id}" />
```

Here the id = 123 and I wish value gets translated to text such as "3IN - 4W - Folded" `<product description>`
I can have id in the bean always and look up for description each time from a cache and translate and display.
For a enum G:"GREEN" struts conveter gets us G stored in database and GREEN displayed on screen.
similarly if it find id=123 and I wish "write a converter" which looks up in the cache (may be a Map of values) and displays description.

Comment: `The Converter's role is to convert a String to an Object and an Object to a String.`

Comment: @RomanC have added code.

Comment: @AleksandrM Is there a way that I can make Struts converter do this kind of conversion..??  or if you have any suggestions pls let me know.  I cannot add the description into the bean that is accessed by action class.  i can just use the id (as translator)